# How can I create JavaScript sliders that emulate the ones on the New York Times "Rent or Buy" web site?

Tags: javascript, html, slider

I love the way the sliders on this web site work. How in the world can I make ones that look and act like them?  In particular, I love that everything they are connected to update on the fly. I love that they are non-linear. They have a large touch input grab zone but a small slider icon. And I love that the don't engage if a mobile users touches them but then slides their finger off. It does a great job of preventing accidental touches.

https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2014/upshot/buy-rent-calculator.html

I tried using a JS library called ionRangeSlider, but it doesn't feel as slick as the NYT ones. And it doesn't prevent accidental touch inputs.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: You should start yourself, and if and when stuck, post the issues you run into. Please see: [help] (1) | [ask] | [mcve] | [help/on-topic] (2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably achieve something similar using a traditional slider coupled with chartJS.

If you're looking for a more exact technology stack, builtwith.com may help:

https://builtwith.com/?https%3a%2f%2fwww.nytimes.com%2finteractive%2f2014%2fupshot%2fbuy-rent-calculator.html